# How to Calculate the Total Probability of Success from Weighted Variables

Tags: probability, percentages

I am trying to determine the total percentage of this project being successful. We have about 5 different variables which each carry a different weight. The weight of the variable is how critical it is to the project. Also, each variable has a percentage tied to it which is the probability of it being successful.

[Charts with Variables, Percentages, and Weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpplO.png)

Total Probability of Success = ????

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.